# Plot a plane in vispy

Tags: python, numpy, vispy

I am plotting a 3D point cloud on an `XYZAxis` with the `Markers` visual. In addition, I would like to plot a plane that shows how these points are separated; in this case, I have the coefficients `c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3` of the plane `c_0x_ + c_1y + c_2z + c_3 = 0`. How can I do this? I've tried using the `Plane` visual, but I'm not sure how to tailor the `Plane` to the coefficients.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `SurfacePlot` visual:

```
coefs = np.array([-10.07375729,  15.61272995,   2.45089647,  33.58025209])
xx = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
yy = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
YY, XX = np.meshgrid(yy, xx)
z = (-coefs[1] * XX- coefs[2] * YY - coefs[0]) * 1. /coefs[3]
plane = SurfacePlot(x=xx, y=yy, z=z, color=(0.3, 0.3, 1, 1), parent=view.scene)
```